# How to? Partial string stored with CCK text field, end users enter the full string in a views exposed filter

Tags: 6, views, entities

I could really do with some pointers...

My scenario is as follows. I have a CCK content type called Part. It has a field called chassis, set to accept unlimited values.

Each part will fit all vehicles where the partial chassis entered on the node matches in some way to the full chassis of the customers car. I say in some way because having spoken to the suppliers there isn't say "the stored chassis will match the first 8 of the full chassis", they say it can be random...

So i am really at a loss... How could I go about providing this search functionality?

Or am I looking at this the wrong way? In terms of my approach...

Many thanks to any kind soul who may help me move forward in the right direction...